# Minecraft Hexxit Suddenly Extreme Lag

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, framerate, minecraft-hexxit

I have a extreme lag problem on my server.

It's a dedicated Server on my local machine with me and up to 4 other players on it. We use the Hexxit-Mod-Pack on 1.5.2. I give my Minecraft 1Gb Memory. Disabling the mods is no option, but without mods it works properly.

We build a small city, with a 'Meteor Shield' (think it's important, because I have less lag without it.) So i run around, placing 'Land Protection Tester'. After a while, I moved a little bit away from my village I have big lags. [image: XXPICTUREXX] The left side explains itselfs, the right side is the server log. Normally I play on about 40 to 60 FPS. But as you see above it's 0 to a maximum of 4 FPS and it does not restabilize even if I wait about half an hour. Do you have any idea how o avoid it except unbuild the 'Meteor Shield'? By the way, the lag only affects ME, not the others.

Maybe any option I can change or a little configuration change?

EDIT: maybe important also: As i encountered the lag, I tried relog. So disconnect, Multiplayer, Connect, then MC crashed with this log:

```
  Minecraft has crashed!      
  ----------------------      

Minecraft has stopped running because it encountered a problem; Ticking screen

A full error report has been saved to C:\Users\foren_000\AppData\Roaming\.technic\modpacks\hexxit\crash-reports\crash-2014-07-08_12.34.38-client.txt - Please include a copy of that file (Not this screen!) if you report this crash to anyone; without it, they will not be able to help fix the crash :(



--- BEGIN ERROR REPORT a5796dc2 --------
Full report at:
C:\Users\foren_000\AppData\Roaming\.technic\modpacks\hexxit\crash-reports\crash-2014-07-08_12.34.38-client.txt
Please show that file to Mojang, NOT just this screen!

Generated 08.07.14 12:34

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Native Method)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Unknown Source)
    at mapwriter.MwUtil.allocateDirectIntBuffer(MwUtil.java:69)
    at mapwriter.map.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:23)
    at mapwriter.map.MapTexture.<init>(MapTexture.java:30)
    at mapwriter.Mw.onClientLoggedIn(Mw.java:392)
    at mapwriter.forge.MwConnectionHandler.clientLoggedIn(MwConnectionHandler.java:52)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.network.NetworkRegistry.clientLoggedIn(NetworkRegistry.java:211)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.network.FMLNetworkHandler.onConnectionEstablishedToServer(FMLNetworkHandler.java:90)
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.NetClientHandler.func_72455_a(NetClientHandler.java:341)
    at net.minecraft.network.packet.Packet1Login.func_73279_a(Packet1Login.java:119)
    at net.minecraft.network.TcpConnection.func_74428_b(TcpConnection.java:461)
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.NetClientHandler.func_72551_d(NetClientHandler.java:266)
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.GuiConnecting.func_73876_c(GuiConnecting.java:51)

-- Affected screen --
Details:
    Screen name: net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiDownloadTerrain

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: MpServer
    All players: 1 total; [EntityClientPlayerMP['KaienRomane'/110596, l='MpServer', x=8,50, y=66,62, z=8,50]]
    Chunk stats: MultiplayerChunkCache: 0
    Level seed: 0
    Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: false
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (8,64,8), Chunk: (at 8,4,8 in 0,0; contains blocks 0,0,0 to 15,255,15), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
    Level time: 0 game time, 0 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x00000 - Unknown?
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
    Forced entities: 1 total; [EntityClientPlayerMP['KaienRomane'/110596, l='MpServer', x=8,50, y=66,62, z=8,50]]
    Retry entities: 0 total; []
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.WorldClient.func_72914_a(WorldClient.java:441)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71396_d(Minecraft.java:2414)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:776)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.5.2
    Operating System: Windows 8.1 (x86) version 6.3
    Java Version: 1.7.0_60, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 259633208 bytes (247 MB) / 429264896 bytes (409 MB) up to 1037959168 bytes (989 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
    AABB Pool Size: 1 (56 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 1 (56 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Suspicious classes: FML and Forge are installed
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 3, tallocated: 63
    FML: MCP v7.51 FML v5.2.23.737 Minecraft Forge 7.8.1.737 Optifine OptiFine_1.5.2_HD_U_D5 68 mods loaded, 68 mods active
    mcp{7.51} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    FML{5.2.23.737} [Forge Mod Loader] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    Forge{7.8.1.737} [Minecraft Forge] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    CodeChickenCore{0.8.7.3} [CodeChicken Core] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    CoFHFramework{1.5.2.5} [CoFH Framework] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ImmibisMicroblocks{55.0.7} [Immibis's Microblocks] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    NotEnoughItems{1.5.2.28} [Not Enough Items] (coremods) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    mod_bspkrsCore{v2.09(1.5.2)} [bspkrsCore] ([1.5.2]bspkrsCorev2.09.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    TreeCapitator{Forge 1.5.2.r14} [TreeCapitator] ([1.5.2]TreeCapitator.Forge.1.5.2.r14.Uni.CoreMod.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    CoFHCore{1.5.2.5} [CoFHCore] (CoFHCore-1.5.2.5.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    CoFHWorld{1.5.2.5} [CoFHWorld] (CoFHCore-1.5.2.5.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    CustomLAN{2.2} [Custom LAN Mod] (CustomPortForge.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ImmibisMicroblocksInstallCheck{55.0.7} [Immibis's Microblocks (Checks for incorrect installation, ignore this)] (immibis-microblocks-55.0.7.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    DamageIndicatorsMod{2.7.0.1} [Damage Indicators] (1.5.2 DamageIndicators v2.7.0.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    AsgardShield_Core{2.0.4} [AsgardShield] (1.5.2AsgardShield_Core_2.0.4Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ASAddon_Hallowed{2.0.0} [AS Addon- Hallowed] (1.5.2ASAddonHallowed_v2.0.0Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    HarkenScythe_Core{2.1.6} [HarkenScythe] (1.5.2HarkenScythe_v2.1.6Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ASAddon_HarkenScythe{2.0.0} [AS Addon- HarkenScythe] (1.5.2ASAddonHarkenScythe_v2.0.0Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ASAddon_NetherEnder{2.0.0} [AS Addon- Nether-Ender] (1.5.2ASAddonNetherEnder_v2.0.0Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ASAddon_ColorAPI{1.0.0} [ASAddon_ColorAPI] (1.5.2AsgardShield_Core_2.0.4Forge.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    BetterStorage{0.6.2.23-hotfix2} [BetterStorage] ([1.5.2]BetterStorage_0.6.2.23-hotfix2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    mod_ArmorBarMod{0.7.1} [Armor Bar Mod] (ArmorBarv0.7.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    Artifice{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ArtificeCompat|Chisel{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: Chisel] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ArtificeCompat|EE3{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: EE3] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ArtificeCompat|Forestry{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: Forestry] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ArtificeCompat|MFR{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: MFR] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ArtificeCompat|Railcraft{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: Railcraft] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ArtificeCompat|Vanilla{1.5.2R1.1.2} [Artifice Compat: Vanilla] (Artifice-1.1.2-182.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    Backpack{1.12.13} [Backpack] (backpack-1.12.13-1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    mod_BackTools{1.5.2v1} [mod_BackTools] (BackTools1.5.2v1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    BattleTowers{1.3.4} [Battle Towers] (BattleTowers_1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    BetterDungeons{1.8} [Better dungeons] (BetterDungeons.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    BiblioCraft{1.3.3} [BiblioCraft] (BiblioCraft[v1.3.3].zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    mod_BuffBarMod{0.7.1} [Buff Bar Mod] (BuffBarv0.7.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ChestTransporter{1.1.6} [Chest Transporter] (chestTransporter_1.1.6_Universal.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    DimDoors{1.5.2R1.4.1RC1} [Dimensional Doors] (DimensionalDoors-1.5.2R1.4.1RC1-194.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    eplus{1.15.4} [Enchanting Plus] (EnchantingPlus-1.15.4.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ExtrabiomesXL{3.13.4} [ExtrabiomesXL] (ExtrabiomesXL-universal-1.5.2-3.13.4.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    hexxitgear{1.5.2R1.0} [Hexxit Gear] (HexxitGear-1.0-23.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ImmibisCore{55.1.6} [Immibis Core] (immibis-core-55.1.6.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    InfernalMobs{1.3.1} [Infernal Mobs] (InfernalMobs_1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    inventorytweaks{1.54b} [Inventory Tweaks] (InventoryTweaks-1.54b.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    MapWriter{2.0} [MapWriter] (mapwriter-2.0.5.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    Meteors{2.10.2} [Falling Meteors] (Meteors Mod V2.10.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    More Bows{1.5_v1} [More Bows mod] (More bows 1.5.2_2 Forge.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    Natura{2.1.5} [Natura] (Natura_1.5.2_2.1.5.1.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    Natura|CompatMineFactoryReloaded{0.1} [Natura compat: MFR] (Natura_1.5.2_2.1.5.1.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    NEIPlugins{1.0.9.3} [NEI Plugins] (NEIPlugins-1.0.9.3.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    LegendGear{1.5.2} [LegendGear] (NMcCoy-LegendGear-1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ObsidiPlates{1.5.0} [Obsidian Pressure Plates] (obsidiplates-1.5.2-universal-1.5.0.13.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    OffLawn{1.0} [offLawn] (OffLawn-1.5.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ProjectZulu|Core{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu Core] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ProjectZulu|Blocks{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu Block and Items] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ProjectZulu|Dungeon{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu Mobs] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ProjectZulu|Mobs{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu Mobs] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    ProjectZulu|World{1.0.3.8} [Project Zulu World] (ProjectZuluCompletev1.0.3.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    QuantumCraft{1.01} [qCraft] (qCraft1.01.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    xreliquary{1.5.2} [Xeno's Reliquary] (Reliquary1.0.6d.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    rftl{1.0} [RottenFleshToLeather] (RottenFleshToLeather-1.5.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    AS_Ruins{10.3} [Ruins Spawning System] (Ruins_1.5.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    secretroomsmod{4.6.0} [SecretRoomsMod] (SecretRoomsMod-universal-4.6.0.283.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    SoulShards{1.0.16} [Soul Shards] (SoulShards-1.0.36-universal-srg.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    TConstruct{1.5.2_1.4.3d7} [Tinkers' Construct] (TConstruct_1.5.2_1.4.3.final.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    TConstruct|CompatMineFactoryReloaded{0.1} [TConstruct Compat: MFR] (TConstruct_1.5.2_1.4.3.final.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    TwilightForest{1.18.1} [The Twilight Forest] (twilightforest-1.18.1.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    WildCaves3{0.4.2} [Wild Caves 3] (WildCaves3-0.4.2.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    chococraft{2.8.8} [Torojima's ChocoCraft] (zzzChococraft_2.8.8.zip) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized->Initialized->Post-initialized->Available
    LWJGL: 2.9.0
    OpenGL: GeForce 210/PCIe/SSE2 GL version 3.3.0, NVIDIA Corporation
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Texture Pack: Default
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory(Native Method)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Unknown Source)
    at mapwriter.MwUtil.allocateDirectIntBuffer(MwUtil.java:69)
    at mapwriter.map.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:23)
    at mapwriter.map.MapTexture.<init>(MapTexture.java:30)
    at mapwriter.Mw.onClientLoggedIn(Mw.java:392)
    at mapwriter.forge.MwConnectionHandler.clientLoggedIn(MwConnectionHandler.java:52)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.network.NetworkRegistry.clientLoggedIn(NetworkRegistry.java:211)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.network.FMLNetworkHandler.onConnectionEstablishedToServer(FMLNetworkHandler.java:90)
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.NetClientHandler.func_72455_a(NetClientHandler.java:341)
    at net.minecraft.network.packet.Packet1Login.func_73279_a(Packet1Login.java:119)
    at net.minecraft.network.TcpConnection.func_74428_b(TcpConnection.java:461)
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.NetClientHandler.func_72551_d(NetClientHandler.java:266)
    at net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.GuiConnecting.func_73876_c(GuiConnecting.java:51)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71407_l(Minecraft.java:1526)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71411_J(Minecraft.java:835)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:760)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
--- END ERROR REPORT fa1dee60 ----------
```

EDIT II: Please do not mention I use x86 Java, just saw it.... will change it now to x64, then I say if it works properly...

Comment: Not an expert in these matters, but 1GB seems awfully low for heavily modded Minecraft. I would try upping it to 2 or even 4 if your system will allow it.

Comment: i use the techniclauncher, it only allows up to 1gb, how may i set it up then? And another point: why does minecraft show only 28% of ram used? even after the lag it is not above 40%?

Comment: Well you are hosting the server so you're loading everything on both the server AND your game client. Its going to be pretty demanding, especially once you start adding new chunks from exploring.  If you go too far too quickly you will really start to feel the lag. What are your computer specs?

Comment: I can play for hours without serious lags, only if i place the proteciotn land tester i get them. My specs are Win 8.1 x64, Intel I3-2130 (3,4Ghz), 4GB RAM, Java 7.. anything forgotten? The server does not say "Cant keep up" as it normally does on lag

Comment: That's pretty interesting,  I'd say to skip the  PLT and just build a base thats either underground or made of obsidian so if you do actually get hit by a meteor, its only going to tickle. My friends and I played that pack for weeks and never had an issue with being hit by one though.

Comment: ofcourse I also have an indestructable bunker, but I want to get that achievement and i need these land tester for that afaik

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about modded minecraft crashes

Answer (score 2):

I just updated my Java 7 (x86) to Java 8 (x64). Now my minecraft works properly, with no freezes. Thanks for all your time.